# Evaluation of a complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial related to Stirling number of 2nd kind

Tags: co.combinatorics, symmetric-functions, stirling-numbers

It is well known that the complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial $h_{n-k}(1,\,2,\,3, ...,\,k-1,\,k)$ equals $S(n,\,k)$ the Stirling number of the second kind. [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_homogeneous_symmetric_polynomial#Relation_with_the_Stirling_numbers)]

During a research project I stumbled upon the following complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial: $h_{n-k}(1,\,2,\,3, ...,\,k-1,\,n)$.

My question is: is the latter symmetric polynomial expressible in nice, simple and/or interpretable terms?

Or is this too much to ask? If so, why?

Comment: How about computing a table for small n and k.and posting it here?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the fact that
$$
\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1-x_i t} = \sum_j h_j(x_1,\dots,x_k) t^j
$$
Writing $h_j = h_{j+k-k}$ we get from your first fact:
$$
\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{1- i t} = \sum_j S(j+k,k) t^j.
$$
Now multiply this by $1/(1-nt)$. We get
$$
\sum_j h_j(1,2,\dots,k,n) t^j = \frac{1}{1-nt} \sum_l S(l+k,k) t^l.
$$
Comparing the coefficient of $t^j$ on both sides we get
$$
h_j(1,2,\dots,k,n) = \sum_{l+m = j} n^m S(l+k,k).
$$
Thus, in your notation,
$$
h_{n-k}(1,2,\dots,k-1,n) = \sum_{l+m = n-k} n^m S(l+k-1,k-1)
$$

Comment: One does not need to use generating functions for this proof; simply note that $h_{n-k}(x_1,\dots,x_k)= h_{n-k}(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1})+x_kh_{n-k-1}(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1})+ x_k^2h_{n-k-2}(x_1,\dots,x_{k-1})+\cdots$.